# How to disambiguate associated types in trait object bounds?

Tags: generics, rust

If I try to define a boxed [`IEvent`](https://docs.rs/stdweb/*/stdweb/traits/trait.IEvent.html) field like this:

```
use stdweb::private::ConversionError;
use stdweb::web::event::IEvent;

struct Foo {
    bar: Box<IEvent<Error = ConversionError>>,
}
```

I get an error like this:

```
error[E0221]: ambiguous associated type `Error` in bounds of `stdweb::traits::IEvent`
  --> src/events.rs:16:21
   |
16 |     bar: Box<IEvent<Error = ConversionError>>,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ambiguous associated type `Error`
   |
note: associated type `stdweb::traits::IEvent` could derive from `stdweb::unstable::TryFrom<stdweb::Reference>`
  --> src/events.rs:16:21
   |
16 |     bar: Box<IEvent<Error = ConversionError>>,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: associated type `stdweb::traits::IEvent` could derive from `stdweb::unstable::TryFrom<stdweb::Value>`
  --> src/events.rs:16:21
   |
16 |     bar: Box<IEvent<Error = ConversionError>>,
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

If you want more information on this error, try using "rustc --explain E0221"
```

How do I write the syntax to set the associated `Error` types (for traits `TryFrom<Value>` and `TryFrom<Reference>`)?

Answer (score 4):

I don't *believe* you can.

Examining what I believe to be the relevant type in the compiler ([`TypeBinding` in `libsyntax`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/4cdbac639af2074b8a07b4391b4e3e28b4118487/src/libsyntax/ast.rs#L1531-L1537)) shows that it only supports a single identifier for the associated type.  So I don't think there's any way to specify the associated types from the field type.

Defining your own intermediate trait doesn't help, since it uses the same syntax to constrain associated types.  Even modifying the traits in `stdweb` doesn't appear to work, as trying to constrain the `TryFrom::Error` types to an associated type in, say, `ReferenceType` produces a cyclic dependency that is rejected by the compiler.  Changing `ReferenceType` to accept a generic type parameter that is used to directly constrain the `Error` types also doesn't satisfy it.

It's possible this is just an edge case that the language simply can't deal with as yet.  If someone else doesn't come up with a solution, I would recommend opening an issue in the [compiler's issue tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/) with a complete motivating example.

The only other solution I can think of is to modify `stdweb` to not use multiple `TryFrom` constraints.

Comment: Oof.  Thanks for the thorough investigation!  I'll file an issue as you suggest if I don't hear anything back.